# Facebook App Development - Authentication using Dialog API using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to integrate my web application with the Facebook platform.

below is my test code,

```
 if ($_REQUEST['error_reason']) {  echo("<script> top.location.href='http://facebook.com'</script>"); }
else {  
    $app_id = "APP_CODE";
    $canvas_page = "https://e3xcp.com/hs/fb/";
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) "&scope=email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_religion_politics,user_website,user_checkins";

    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
    if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
          echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    } else {
          echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"] . "<BR><BR>");
          print_r($data);
          echo "<BR><BR>". $data['oauth_token'] . "<BR><BR>";

          $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=". trim($data['oauth_token']); 
          $json_data = file_get_contents($graph_url);
          $me = json_decode($json_data);
          echo $me->id;
    }
}
```

There are two issues,

1. When Authenticating (a new user), when the user press "Allow" button, the browser navigates back and forth between my canvas page and the facebook server.
2. When an authenticated user accessed the app, i get an error saying,

   ```
   **> Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=200335043341031|2.axhed5PlPjICLqIN2ElgGA__.3600.1304254800.1-100001278552830|ez-LK5f_ymd-q9Ju4qa7zAvjEgo) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\E3XCP.COM\httpdocs\hs\FB\index.php on line 19**
   ```

But when I copy and paste the GRAPH URL

```
  ***https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=200335043341031|2.axhed5PlPjICLqIN2ElgGA__.3600.1304254800.1-100001278552830|ez-LK5f_ymd-q9Ju4qa7zAvjEgo*** it returns the correct output
```

There are two authentication samples given in the Facebook Developers documentation and i tried both methods.

The app link is [http://apps.facebook.com/slhoroscope](http://apps.facebook.com/slhoroscope/)
Help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use the **Canvas Page** and not the **Canvas Url**, i.e `$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/slhoroscope/";`
2. It has something to do with your PHP configuration, most likely the openssl extension.

Comment: @megazoid: I suppose `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. As for how to install it, you need to check with the environment support forum/tutorials (xampp,wampserver...whatever you have installed on your machine)

Comment: ifaour, thanks a lot mate ... first issue is sorted (URL navigation issue) after using the app url instead of my url. This is one key piece of information left out in the facebook documentation..

Comment: @megazoid: While they do use `YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE` in their [example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) I do agree that they should further explain this. They shouldn't consider a *single* piece of info as obvious/granted!

Comment: @ifaour, Ok i have followed your instructions, and found that my PHP support for OpenSSL is disabled. how do i enable it?

Comment: @megazoid: as I said, it really depends on your environment. For instance, I use Wampserver (on my windows machine) and it's a simple right click on the Package App icon on the start bar and "tick" the openssl!

Comment: @ifaour, my app is hosted on a Win2003 VPS with Plesk plnel.. any ideas?

Comment: @megazoid: Not really, you best bet is to contact the Host support or check the host's wiki website.

Comment: @ifaour, I have put a support ticket to my VPS host support. Lets wait and see what they say.

Comment: @ifaour, I tried the same script on a different server which i had and it works perfectly. So YES your answer is 100% correct here and I will get my VPS guys to sort the OpenSSL issue for my VPS. Thanks a million mate. You saved me lot of trouble .....

Comment: @ifaour, problem solved. :) checkout the app at http://apps.facebook.com/slhoroscope

Comment: Why should someone use the **Canvas Page Url**? The latest response on the "[misconfiguration error for mobile web app](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/124226157757972)" bug says that we should use the **mobile site url**.